# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker

After starting up postgres on docker any attempt to connect to the database results in the following;

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

*Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8*

I have looked at similar issues and my ports are assigned as such;

```
ports:
 - 5432:5432
```

Details

- Flask server using venv
- Windows 10

Additional Details

Dockerfile (for postgres)

```
FROM postgres:9.6-alpine

COPY init-db /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

application file (FLASK_APP) THIS IS THE COMMAND THAT BREAKS IT

```
@application.cli.command(with_appcontext=True)
def create_db():
    db.engine.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS fuzzystrmatch;")

    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
```

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                  NAMES
f04ca2725c96        taxai_ml                 "gunicorn --worker-c…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8900->5000/tcp                 taxai_ml_1
032fd31432af        stripemock/stripe-mock   "/stripe-mock -http-…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:12111-12112->12111-12112/tcp   taxai_stripe_1
795b2ff4d7d5        redis:3.2.11-alpine      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                 taxai_redis_1

Comment: could you provide additional information? like Dockerfile for your postgres and your flask? the output of docker ps or any other docker commands that might be relevant

Comment: The output of the docker-compose up -d is succesful. It is only when I run the create_db() command that the error message pops up.

Comment: What I was saying is that more information looks like to be required in order to fully understand the problem. Knowing how your service is defined will help, is this a compose of app and db? is your app connecting to an existing db elsewhere? before calling the cli command how is your connection against database being defined? have you tested your python code outside docker?, etc